# Make footer appear at the bottom of Report Page even if there is no data

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2014

I'm working on SSRS Report.

How to make footer appear at the bottom of Report page, when there is no data to show in tablix?

Currently all reports footer is appearing immediate next to the Tablix Last Row. It should always appear at the bottom of every page whether data is present or not.

[image]
*Please help me!*

Comment: see when you are viewing that report and no record was there then footer will appears at the top. its not possible to arrange it at bottom side. for better clarification add screen shot of design mode.

Comment: @Manoj - please check above image for...

Answer (score 0):

Put an empty Rectangle item to the right of your data tablix, with it's height as the minimum height you want the report body to take up. Even if the tablix has no data, the Rectangle will act as a minimum height.

In my screenshots the rectangle is blue and the footer is yellow to highlight what happens. You can make your rectangle whatever colour and width you want. From my testing in SSRS 2008 R2, this still works even if the rectangle has no colour and the report's `ConsumeContainerWhitespace` property is True.

[image: rect with data][image: rect without data]

If you're printing the report or exporting it to PDF etc., you shouldn't have to worry about this. The page size of the print/export will automatically put the footer at the very bottom of each page, regardless of the body contents.